# Monadic function of `(a -> m (Either e b)) -> Either e a -> m (Either e b)`?

Tags: haskell, monads, either

Is there a way to write this function in a more "monadic" way, instead of resorting to pattern matching on `Either`?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

calculate :: (Monad m) => (a -> m (Either e b)) -> Either e a -> m (Either e b)
calculate f = \case
  Left err   -> return $ Left err
  Right vals -> f vals
```

Specifically, for my use case, `m` is `IO`; `f` is a function that takes in input and produces some `IO` effect or fails, and the input is something that could have failed already.

Maybe using `ExceptT`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, looks like `ExceptT` to me.  Though I would probably not use a function with this signature -- instead, I would use `ExceptT` more broadly, and then this function is just `(=<<)`.  Of course this is guesswork based on the use case.

But if you must:

```
calculate :: (Monad m) => (a -> m (Either e b)) -> Either e a -> m (Either e b)
calculate f m = runExceptT (ExceptT . f =<< ExceptT m)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `traverse` and `join`:

```hs
calculate :: (Monad f, Traversable f, Applicative m) => (a1 -> m (f a2)) -> f a1 -> m (f a2)
calculate f e = join <$> traverse f e
```

Note the more general type signature. That's what GHC infers. Instead of `Either e` any type is sufficient as long as it has instances for `Monad` and `Traversable`. Also, `m` doesn't need to have a `Monad`, `Applicative` is enough.

`ExceptT` works as well (the first one doesn't change the type of the result, the second one goes all in on `ExceptT`):

```hs
calculate :: (Monad m) => (a -> ExceptT e m b) -> Either e a -> m (Either e b)
calculate f e = runExceptT $ ExceptT (pure e) >>= f

calculate2 :: (Monad m) => (a -> ExceptT e m b) -> Either e a -> ExceptT e m b
calculate2 f e = ExceptT (pure e) >>= f
```

I personally would prefer the former, because I find it easier to grasp without `ExceptT`.